Uniqueness and existence of maps
I am currently reading the Berkeley lectures on Perfectoid Spaces by Scholze and Weinstein. In the section "The adic open unit disk over $\mathbb{Z}_p$" we encounter from Proposition 4.2.6 we have,
$\mathbb{\kappa} : Y \to [0,\infty]$
that satisfies certain properties and in the proof, Scholze constructs the map by
$\kappa(x) = \frac{|log(T(x')|}{|log(p(x'))|}$, where $x'$ is the maximal generalization of $x$. He further claims that such a map is unique and surjective.
Reference link of the text : https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/scholze/Berkeley.pdf
My questions:
i) Why do we need maximal generalization and what is the problem when if we just have $x$ ? I get that having maximal generalization changes nothing though cause they have same kernel.
ii) Surjectivity is quite clear to me. But why unique ?

It would be helpful to state the full background in the question (what properties the map is supposed to satisfy), or at least say more specifically where this is located in the reference.

@Vik78 edited above.

If I understand correctly, Prop 4.2.5 tells us that maximal generalizations correspond to real-valuations, and only when $\lvert p(-)\rvert$ and $\lvert T(-)\rvert$ are real, could you define their logarithms.

The uniqueness seems to be completely formal: the rational numbers $q$ such that $\lvert T(x)\rvert\ge\lvert p(x)\rvert^q$ have an infimum, and $\kappa(x)$ is necessarily this infimum, by surjectivity.

@Z.M can you be a bit more clearer and post this as an answer instead of in comments ? It might be helpful for a lot

I am not confident enough to write such an answer: I am not working in this field. When I commented above, I was not 100% sure.

Ahhh ok, seems fine
